# Request Max Retries TOR

Tags: python, sockets, python-requests, proxies

I am trying to connect to TOR's localhost loopback and send data through it.
The address I am using is:

```
127.0.0.1:9050
```

I am using the following script to do this:

```
import requesocks, requests
session = requesocks.session()
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
                   'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
print session.get("https://api.ipify.org?format=json").json()
```

It is supposed to retrieve my IP and print it. However, it gives the following error:

```
Max retries exceeded with url: https://api.ipify.org/?format=json
```

I can verify that TOR is up and running. What could be the problem raising this exception?

Comment: Code runs fine for me.  calling .json() would error though, you want .content, does `session.get("http://ipecho.net/plain").content` throw the same error?

Comment: Yes, it does throw the same error... Is there any specific version of TOR I need? I have the regular browser installed; but is there a command line or something I am missing? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: How did you start tor? You do actually have tor running as a service and not just the browser bundle?

Comment: How would I run tor as a service? it's not accessible via command line

Comment: What os are you using?

Comment: Windows, but I got it working. I had to install the "expert" installer and add the exe to my PATH. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. I had to install the "expert" installer and add the exe to my PATH. Thank you